# How to read the employee jobtype using ipp.net sdk v3(QuickBooks online API)? I can't find any property in 'Employee' for jobtype

Tags: asp.net, quickbooks-online

How to read the employee jobtype using ipp.net sdk v3(QuickBooks online API)? I can't find any property in 'Employee' for jobtype.
I have employee records with "Job Type".
All other records I can read, but jobtype is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from Qucikbooks moderator. We cant read 'JobType' as it is not supported by the API yet.